# React router not rendering components anymore except the default one

Tags: reactjs, react-router, navbar

I took a break from my project for a day and today I come back to and suddenly i have an issue with my react router. I was messing around with adding more components but deleted them and now my Homepage, about, or gallery component dont render when I change the page with then navbar. The url still changes if i click on gallery to /gallery but the `<h1>Gallery page</h1>` does not show up anymore.

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import NavigationBar from './components/navbar';
import About from './components/About';
import Home from './components/homepage';
import Gallery from './components/gallery';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
class App extends Component {
  state = {};
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <NavigationBar />
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
            <Route path="/about" component={About} />
            <Route path="/gallery" component={Gallery} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Homepage

```
import '../css/homepage.scss';

class Homepage extends Component {
  state = {};
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Homepage;
```

About

```
class About extends Component {
  state = {};
  render() {
    return <h1>About</h1>;
  }
}

export default About;
```

Gallery

```
class gallery extends Component {
  state = {};
  render() {
    return <h1>Gallery page</h1>;
  }
}

export default gallery;
```

Nav code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav';
import { link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import '../css/navbar.scss';
import $ from 'jquery';
import logo from '../images/logo.png';
class NavigationBar extends Component {
  state = {};
  render() {
    return (
      <Navbar fixed="top" className="navbarr" bg="light" expand="sm">
        <Navbar.Brand
          activeClassName="nav-link--active"
          className="BrandLink"
          href="/"
        >
          <img
            alt=""
            src={logo}
            width="45"
            height="30"
            className="d-inline-block align-top"
          />
          BRAND NAME HERE
        </Navbar.Brand>
        <Navbar.Toggle />
        <Navbar.Collapse className="justify-content-end">
          <Nav className="ml-auto">
            <Nav.Link
              className="NavLink"
              activeClassName="nav-link--active"
              href="/About"
            >
              About
            </Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link
              className="NavLink"
              activeClassName="nav-link--active"
              href="/Gallery"
            >
              Gallery
            </Nav.Link>
          </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Navbar>
    );
  }
}

export default NavigationBar;
```

Comment: can you try it with `component={() => <Home/>}` I had a similiar issue some times back, but I'm not 100% sure if this was the solution

Comment: @davbuc doesnt work still. it seems that react only renders the homepage component

Comment: could you provide a codepen/sandbox.io for that so one can test this with the actual code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving your default route to the end of routes. i.e.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import NavigationBar from './components/navbar';
import About from './components/About';
import Home from './components/homepage';
import Gallery from './components/gallery';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
class App extends Component {
  state = {};
  render() {
    return (
     <Fragment>
      <div className="App">
        <NavigationBar />
      </div>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/about" component={About} />
          <Route path="/gallery" component={Gallery} />
          <Route path="/" component={Home} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
     </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

The problem is with you Navbar components. Try this one:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Navbar from "react-bootstrap/Navbar";
import Nav from "react-bootstrap/Nav";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "../css/navbar.scss";
import $ from "jquery";
import logo from "../images/logo.png";
class NavigationBar extends Component {
  state = {};
  render() {
    return (
      <Navbar fixed="top" className="navbarr" bg="light" expand="sm">
        <Navbar.Brand activeClassName="nav-link--active" className="BrandLink">
          <Link to="/">
            <img
              alt=""
              src={logo}
              width="45"
              height="30"
              className="d-inline-block align-top"
            />
            BRAND NAME HERE
          </Link>
        </Navbar.Brand>
        <Navbar.Toggle />
        <Navbar.Collapse className="justify-content-end">
          <Nav className="ml-auto">
            <Nav.Link className="NavLink" activeClassName="nav-link--active">
              <Link to="/about">About</Link>
            </Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link className="NavLink" activeClassName="nav-link--active">
              <Link to="/gallery">Gallery</Link>
            </Nav.Link>
          </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Navbar>
    );
  }
}

export default NavigationBar;
```

Comment: The only text that is shown is the one from the component homepage, no matter if i switch to other pages or not.

Comment: Can you please add the `NavigationBar` code as well?

Comment: Still no success. I know the components imported in app.js work and can be rendered because i did this
``` <Home />
<Gallery />
<Shop />
```
and they all showed up however they just dont want to render when I put a <Router> tag in. even if I manually enter the url as /About the about component h1 doesnt show up.